# ValueError: X has 5 features, but MultinomialNB is expecting 15940 features as input

Tags: python, valueerror

```
import pickle as pkl
import re
import nltk
import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import  CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

#model that was trained
model=pkl.load(open(r'C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\SENTIMENT\code\main\newOwnModelNV.pkl','rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    #initialize the data
    data = []
    data =  [str(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    
    #data preprocessing in the data taken from user input
    stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
    def parser(x):
        x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x.lower()) 
        x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(stopwords)]
        x = [w for w in x if wordnet.synsets(w)]
        return ' '.join(x)

    #applying the function
    data1 = []
    for x in range(len(data)):
        data1.append(parser(data[x]))

    #vectorize it
    vt = CountVectorizer()
    newData = vt.fit_transform(data1).toarray()

    prediction=model.predict_proba(newData)
    output='{0:.{1}f}'.format(prediction[0][1], 2)
    
    if output>str(0.8):
        return render_template('home.html',pred='High probability of sarcasm: {}'.format(output))
    else:
        return render_template('home.html',pred='Low probability of sarcasm: {}'.format(output))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Im building a sentiment analysis on web but the problem i got now is the expected features are not the same with my X features. after the model that has been build predict the accuracy, it will show how much of a sarcasm it is.

Answer (score 0):

To process data is commonly used a data frame instance, for example:

```
>>> data
                                                text  label
0  I only went to see this movie because I have a...      0
1  I felt that Ashton did a great job in the Butt...      0
2  Some of the scenes were just not believable an...      1
3  The special effects were pretty good and more ...      0
4       Not sure I'll ever go deep sea fishing again      1
5  I expected a little more emotion in the film t...      0
6  Definitely a movie that could've been seen on DVD      1
7  This is a pale imitation of Officer and a Gent...      1
8  There is NO chemistry between Kutcher and the ...      1
9     The dialog is wooden, the situations hackneyed      0
```

Where text and label have the corresponding values for
text to be analyzed and labels 0-1 (negative, positive)
and you could define `X, y` to perform a logistic regression to sentiment classifier, you need to split your data to take 75% data for training and 25% data for test, is needed to import `train_test_split` from **sklearn** and by this way is
possible to create a vector for each string and fit both (train, test) to apply logisitic regression.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#...
X = data["text"]
y = data["label"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0) 

cv = CountVectorizer() 
ctmTr = cv.fit_transform(X_train) 
X_test_dtm = cv.transform(X_test)

model = LogisticRegression() 
model.fit(ctmTr, y_train)

y_pred_class = model.predict(X_test_dtm)

# get the accuracy score of the test data. 
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_class)
```

Instead of use data as a `dataframe` instance without loading any files (csv, xlsx, json)
i would recommend to use [vaderSentiment](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.vader.html#module-nltk.sentiment.vader)
that could help you to perform this task, install it by running `pip install vaderSentiment` in your command prompt, by
using `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` you would have a fixed compound result of score, that is distribuided in positive >= 0.05, neutral > -0.05 and negative <= -0.05

```py
>>> from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
>>> sentences = ["The book was good.",  # positive sentence
...              "At least it isn't a horrible book.",  # negated negative sentence with contraction
...              "The book was only kind of good.", # qualified positive sentence is handled correctly (intensity adjusted)
...              "The plot was good, but the characters are uncompelling and the dialog is not great.", # mixed negation sentence
...              "Today SUX!",  # negative slang with capitalization emphasis
...              "Today only kinda sux! But I'll get by, lol", # mixed sentiment example with slang and constrastive conjunction "but"
...              "Make sure you :) or :D today!",  # emoticons handled
...              "Catch utf-8 emoji such as such as �� and �� and ��",  # emojis handled
...              "Not bad at all"  # Capitalized negation
...              ]
>>>
>>> analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
>>> for sentence in sentences:
...     vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
...     print("{:-<65} {}".format(sentence, str(vs)))
...
The book was good.----------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.508, 'pos': 0.492, 'compound': 0.4404}
At least it isn't a horrible book.------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.678, 'pos': 0.322, 'compound': 0.431}
The book was only kind of good.---------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.697, 'pos': 0.303, 'compound': 0.3832}
The plot was good, but the characters are uncompelling and the dialog is not great. {'neg': 0.327, 'neu': 0.579, 'pos': 0.094, 'compound': -0.7042}
Today SUX!------------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.779, 'neu': 0.221, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.5461}
Today only kinda sux! But I'll get by, lol----------------------- {'neg': 0.127, 'neu': 0.556, 'pos': 0.317, 'compound': 0.5249}
Make sure you :) or :D today!------------------------------------ {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.294, 'pos': 0.706, 'compound': 0.8633}
Catch utf-8 emoji such as such as  and  and ------------------ {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.615, 'pos': 0.385, 'compound': 0.875}
Not bad at all--------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.513, 'pos': 0.487, 'compound': 0.431}
```

now supposing `data` is a list of strings like the above, it could be implemented like

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

import nltk
from string import punctuation
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('stopwords')

set(stopwords.words('english'))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    data = []
    data =  [str(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    
    stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') 
    def parser(x):
        x = re.sub('[^a-z\s]', '', x.lower()) 
        x = [w for w in x.split() if w not in set(stopwords)]
        x = [w for w in x if nltk.corpus.wordnet.synsets(w)]
        return ' '.join(x)
        
    data1 = []
    for x in range(len(data)):
        data1.append(parser(data[x]))
        
    sa = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    dd = sa.polarity_scores(text=data1)
    compound = round((1 + dd['compound'])/2, 2)
    return render_template('form.html', final=compound, text1=data, text2=dd['pos'],text5=dd['neg'],text4=compound,text3=dd['neu'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

form.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.c11{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

</style>
        <title>{{ title }} Sentiment Analysis</title>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div class="container c11" >
    <div class="container-fluid p-5 bg-success text-white text-center">
        <h1>Sentiment Analysis VADER Sentiment</h1>
        <p>A machine learning end to end flask web app for <b>"Sentiment Analysis" </b>model created using Scikit-learn &amp; VADER Sentiment.</p> 
    </div>
        </br></br><div align="center">
            <form method="POST">
                <textarea name="text1" placeholder="Say Something: ...." rows="10" cols="109"></textarea><br><br>

                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        {% if final %}
        
<!--result start -->        
      </br></br>  <div align="center">
           </br>  </br>
           <h2 class="bg-success text-white">The Sentiment of</h2>
           '{{ text1 }}'  
            <h2>Score table</h2>


<div class="container table-responsive-sm">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>SENTIMENT METRIC</th>
    <th>SCORE</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Positive</td>
    <td>{{text2}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Neutral</td>
    <td>{{text3}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Negative</td>
    <td>{{text5}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Compound</td>
    <td>{{text4}}</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

            {% else %}
            <p></p>
            {% endif %}
        </div></br></br>
<!--result end -->          
        
        
  </div>  </body>
</html>
```

[image: out]